# Does volatile mean it is thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, compiler-optimization

In Java, when we want to ensure that compiler should not do optimization by keeping a local copy of a variable, then we make the variable volatile. Using the variable as volatile ensures that the threads would not use a local copy of the variable but they would use the variable as it is stored in the main memory. But, does it mean that the volatile variable is thread-safe? Also how does it differ in case of a primitive type and in case we use a user defined object?

Comment: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`volatile` means that the value will always be fresh; if another thread put a new object into the variable before you, you will see that object.

It does not change the behavior of the value; you cannot magically make an object thread-safe.

Comment: Depending on what you consider "the value," `volatile` doesn't even guarantee freshness for mutable classes. If the class is immutable and final, then marking its reference `volatile` *will* make it thread-safe.

Comment: @yshavit: If the variable is `final`, then `volatile` won't make any difference, AFAIK.

Comment: By final class, I meant that the class is marked `final` (can't be extended), not that its reference is marked `final`. A field `final List<Foo> list = ArrayList<Foo>` isn't threadsafe, because `ArrayList` isn't immutable. But I was referring to the fact that a `volatile String` is thread safe (not counting atomicity with other fields), because `String` is immutable.

Comment: I see; I misunderstood you.  Yes.

Answer (score 3):

not at all,in fact,`volatile` means that's the value can be seen by another thread at once, but `don't` mean that it's thread safe, it's not thread safe.

you can see this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html and find the keyworkd `volatile Fields`

another refer here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html

Answer (score 0):

volatile variable ensures visiblity and is not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile is usually most appropriate for 'simple' state.  Ex. a boolean member variable that may be set to tell a worker thread to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

value of volatile variable will never be stored thread locally.

all reads and writes go to main memory.

[meaning of volatile is different depending on the version of Java (i.e till Java 1.4 and after Java5.0).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java)

[one more link about volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)

Comment: Volatile does not necessarily mean a write to main memory. It means that each thread will read the most up to date value.  You can read on cache coherence to see how this is possible